# Sharing Thread's public properties

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

My class is inherited from TThread with multiple properties, one of them is TAdoDataSet. My thread creates its own TAdoConnection and a TAdoDataSet. My questions are:
1- is it safe to use the DataSet(MyThread.dataset) in the main thread AFTER MyThread is terminated?.
2- is there a better technique for implementing this requirement? I mean, creating a thread that open a dataset and then using the dataset in the main thread ? CAllBack function or PostMessage?

```
TmyProc =Procedure (Msg:TmyMsg) of object;

  TmyThread = Class(TThread)
  private
    FConnection: TAdoConnection;
    FMyDataset :TAdoDataSet;
    FmyProc: TMyProc;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    property myProc: TmyProc read FmyProc;
  public
    Constructor Create(myProc:TmyProc;
                      ConnectionString: WideString);
    property MyDataSet: TAdoDataSet read FMyDataset 
  end;

constructor TmyThread .Create(Susp:Boolean; myProc:TmyProc; 
   ConnectionString: WideString);
begin

// here I create the connection and mydataset;
// and my callback comes from main thread;
FmyProc := myProc; 

inherited Create(Susp);
end;


procedure TmyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  // here I open the connection and myDataset
  CoUninitialize();
end;


In the main thread :

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mt:=TmyThread.Create(True,ACallBack,ADOConnection1.ConnectionString);
  mt.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  mt.OnTerminate:= OnThredDone;
  mt.Resume;
end;
```

3- As you see in the code above, freeonterminate := True, but MyThread stay alive when I test it using : if Assigned(MyThread).

Comment: Likely the dataset can only be accessed from the thread that created. Further, using FreeOnTerminate means that you can't refer to the thread after you've started it, unless you.take great care in the OnTerminated event.

Comment: how about moving the Connection and the DataSet to be  properties in the MainThread and accessing them via MyThrea using Synchronize(MyDataSet) ?

Comment: Why bother with a thread if all your code runs in the main thread? Also, you can't synchronize objects, you synchronize methods.

Comment: Another thread dedicated to open the connection and the dataset, so users can Cancel or do something else instead of waiting. Yes synchronize( OpenMyDataSet ). MyThread.Execute begin synchronize( OpenMyDataSet ) end;

Comment: That just runs the code in the main thread.

Comment: ADO uses apartment-threaded COM objects that have affinity to the thread that creates them.  You can't use ADO across thread boundaries unless you manually marshal the COM objects using `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()`/`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()` or `IGlobalInterfaceTable`.

Comment: I see all sorts of things wrong here. For example, in the thread's constructor, you're calling `inherited` at the END, instead of the BEGINNING. I'd be surprised if this works at all for you, since technically, at the moment you're assigning `FmyProp`, the thread isn't even created yet. Not to mention, your thread's definition *doesn't even have such a field defined*. Please show us *real* code.

Comment: Also, don't use `Resume`. You're supposed to call `Start` instead. Also, *never* call `inherited` inside your `TThread.Execute` procedure. That should be raising an abstract error.

Comment: `if Assigned(MyThread)` simply checks if *your* pointer is `nil` or not. It has nothing to do with whether the thread is still running, or created at all. This alone is a whole topic of its own.

Comment: @jerry Calling inherited at the end of the constructor is bad style but in this case it works fine. The instance exists at this point and a simple field assignment is fine. I think that when inherited would mean calling an abstract, that inherited call is removed.

Answer (score -1):

This is not thread safe. In Delphi the call

Assigned(MyThread)

merely tests for nil. It is the same as

nil <> MyThread

However, in Delphi, calling Free on an object *does not set the object pointer to nil.*

```
MyThread.Free;
if Assigned(MyThread) then  //this will return true
begin
  MyThrerad.MyDaSet.First; //and this will give you an access violation!
end;
```

Delphi has a built in FreeAndNil procedure which ensures the object pointer is set to nil. People should use that.